# Function is not returning last assigned value but the initial value only

Tags: javascript, protractor

In my protractor code this JavaScript function is not returning the latest assigned value. This function assigned value correctly but returned only the initial value. I cant figure it why ?here it is -

```
const getSum = function () {
        let totalPrice=0;
        for(let i=1; i<=4; i++ ) {

          element.all(by.tagName('tr')).then(function (iRow) {

              iRow[i].element(by.css('td:nth-child(4)')).getText().then(function (text) {

                  let iPriceData = text.split(' ');
                  console.log(iPriceData[1])
                  let iPrice = parseInt(iPriceData[1]);
                  totalPrice = iPrice+totalPrice;
                  console.log(totalPrice)
              })

          })

        }

    console.log(totalPrice)

        return totalPrice;
};
//calling function

let sum = getSum();
consol.log(sum)
```

Output for 1st console.log(totalPrice) within for loop are - 100000, 185000,250000,300000.

Output for 2nd consol.log(totalPrice) is 0.

Output for consol.log(sum) is 0.

Why it is returning initial value of totalPrice instead of the latest value which is 300000 for totalPrice  ?
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: `.then` ... shows you have asynchrony in your code - you're returning `totalPrice` before any asynchronous code completes . `const getSum = async function () {` and `await element.all(..........etc` should be enough to fix it - but, I'd convert all the code to use `await` instead, because mixing async/await with .then is not good practice

Comment: @Bravo is it not possible to get desired return value by using `.then`?

Comment: @Bravo thank you. According to your advice its working fine!